# Android use horizontal progress bar from custom dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I need a little information about how can I interact with my Horizontal Progress Dialog in my custom dialog layout. Here is the xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:text="Communicating with Stampii..." />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code which I use to create the dialog :

```
    private void createCancelProgressDialog() {
    cancelDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    cancelDialog.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sync_bars, null));
    cancelDialog.setTitle("Synchronization!");
    cancelDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = cancelDialog.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

So if anyone have suggestions please don't be shy.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
View dialogRoot = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sync_bars, null);
cancelDialog.setView(dialogRoot);
ProgressBar hbar = (ProgressBar) dialogRoot.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
```

you have to reference to your progress bar to interact with it.